# Getting a Windows Store App validated for submission, if it starts out by asking the user to login to facebook?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have made an app for Windows Store Apps that needs the user to log in to facebook for it to make sense. I use the Authenticaiton Broker and it pops up as the first ting when the app launches.

When i run the developer tools WACK tool , it fails :

```
Error Found: The crashes and hangs test detected the following errors:
Application 20055S-Innovations.FacebookFanApp_1.0.0.6_neutral__z1vybpgpdtf9j was detected by Windows Error Reporting and experienced a crash or hang.
```

I dont know if thats related to it using the authentication broker ? Because if I run it myself it works fine and I just login and the app works.

Comment: Does your app work find if you disable all network access? You may need to catch an exception during authentication. This can happen if there is no networks access or if it is behind a firewall.

Comment: it was due to pressing back in the authentication broker.